# No such file or directory when reading Properties File in Java from one Class but not another

Tags: java, exception, ioexception, fileinputstream

I am trying to read a properties folder from this path with respect to the repository root:

```
rest/src/main/resources/cognito.properties
```

I have a Class `CognitoData` from this path: `rest/src/main/java/com/bitorb/admin/webapp/security/cognito/CognitoData.java` which loads the Properties folder using this code, and it runs fine:

```
new CognitoProperties().loadProperties("rest/src/main/resources/cognito.properties");
```

```
@Slf4j
public class CognitoProperties {

    public  Properties loadProperties(String fileName) {

        Properties cognitoProperties = new Properties();

        try {
            @Cleanup
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            cognitoProperties.load(fileInputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Error occured. Exception message was [" + e.getMessage() + "]");
        }

        return cognitoProperties;

    }

}
```

However, when I call `CognitoData` from a test class located in `rest/src/test/java/com/bitorb/admin/webapp/security/cognito/CognitoServiceTest.java` , I get this error:

```
[rest/src/main/resources/cognito.properties (No such file or directory)]
```

Can anybody shed light on why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File directory is not actually relative in that case. You need to provide appropriate file path for this. If you are already using spring boot, then
you can change your code to:

```
// this will read file from the resource folder.
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader()
                          .getResourceAsStream("cognito.properties");

cognitoProperties.load(inputStream);
```

Otherwise you need to provide the full absolute path. `new CognitoProperties().loadProperties("/absolutepath/..../cognito.properties")`

Comment: even if using spring boot only supplying cognito.properties is not enough as the FileInputStream constructor alone is not able to transfer that to an absolute address

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're using for testing, but I suspect that the working directory when you run tests is not the project root.

One solution is to use an absolute path instead:

```
/absolute/path/to/project/rest/src/main/resources/cognito.properties
```

Or maybe check what is the working directory during testing and see if it can be changed to the project root.